# Search view actionbar like instagram android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, instagram, searchview

I want implement search view actionbar with tabs, but viewpaper->fragment (3 tabs->3 viewpaper-> 3 fragment). How to pass value from searchview to 3 viewpaper(3 fragment) when on keypress change(or submit). I have no idea. Thanks

http://postimg.org/image/9jwvc6i8l/

Comment: add search view in menu for fragment where you want to show it.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: Ok. I solved. Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same difficulty, can you tell me how you solved it? thank you!

Answer (score -1):

in activity has viewpager:

```
Fragment page = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.viewpager + ":" + viewPager.getCurrentItem());

Fragment1 fragment1 = (Fragment1) page;

page.function1();
```